# Watir-webdriver, cannot interact with a div popup

Tags: javascript, ruby, popup, watir-webdriver

I cannot figure out a way to interact with the highlighted HTML:

[image: buy item in js modal]

When I click on a link, an interactive modal appears, which has a table to allow user to buy parts. Also, the modal has links that open up new sections within the modal.

I have tried to write step definitions but cannot get test to pass. See below for my (latest attempt) code:

```
When /^I click on the Buy icon of loan part selected$/ do
  @browser.div(:id, 'modal_loan_parts_table').link(:text, 'Buy').click
end
```

The error I keep getting is `element not located`. Can someone please direct me to enlightenment?

Here is the error that occured:

```
  unable to locate element, using {:id=>"modal_loan_parts_table", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
  ./step_definitions/secondarymkt_buying_lp.rb:62:in `/^I click on the Buy icon of loan part selected$/'
  secondarymkt_buying_lp.feature:27:in `When I cllick on the Buy icon of loan part selected'
```

Many Thanks Guys!

Comment: What is the full error? And are you sure the div id is `modal_loan_parts_modal` - it is not in the part of the html shown?

Comment: Another possibility: The "modal" that appears is a section of HTML contained in an iframe?

Comment: Please provide link to the page, if it is public. Or link to a similar public page.

Comment: Hi folks, apologies for the div id, it's actually 'modal_loan_parts_table'.

Comment: Hi Željko, unfortunately I can't provide a link to the page and we don't have a page on our site with similar functionality. It's actually a complete re-work of one of the sites hence no examples. sorry

Comment: I could use xpath, but I really don't want to and would rather use it as a last resort. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution without using xpath. Here is my code and it works:

```
When /^I click on the Buy icon of loan part selected$/ do
  @browser.div(:id, 'details-ajax-modal').wait_until_present
  @browser.div(:id, 'details-ajax-modal').exists?
  @browser.link(:class, 'modal-buy').wait_until_present
  @browser.link(:class, 'modal-buy').click
end
```

Many thanks to everyone.

Comment: This seems more complicated than it has to be. I would think you could just do `@browser.link(:class, 'modal-buy').when_present.click`?

Comment: Used @browser.link(:class, 'modal-buy').when_present.click, unfortunately this step did not work. When running the test, it could not find the element. I know my code is not pretty, but it's doing the job without using xpath :). Once again many thanks Justin for taking the time out to help me out.